# Manipulate the form field values before rendering in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have to actually reset the values of the fields of a model Form, every time the form is rendered. So, lets say everytime a user fills the form, I store the values to a different table and next time when the form is rendered the values are reset to specified data. Again, when the user saves the form, the values are added to the different table and so no. This is quite weird but I need to implement this.

So, how am I supposed to reset the values of a model form before the form is displayed. Definitely, the model belonging to that form is updated with the new values everytime. But I need to reset them when rendered again for edit.

Let me pinpoint what I actually need. I need to override the field values during edit. So if a model was saved with field A having value 'value1'. I need to change this field's value to 'specified value' during edit. So even if the user then changes it to value 2 and saves it. During edit, I again want to have the value set to 'specified value' in the rendered form. It is independent of the values in the database

Answer (score 0):

You can set form values using initial value:

```
form = MyForm(initial={'field1': value1, 'field2': value2, 'field3': value3})
```

Comment: Actually it's not about initial values only. After I submit the form with those initial values, I copy that data and save to a different table and reset them for the current table/model. Now when I edit that model, I need to get those initial values again. This is quite weird but trust me it is what I need

Comment: Well I have accomplished the task using simple javascript. I don't think if this is the best solution but I changed the field values using javascript when the document is ready. Just used some javascript at the extrahead and changed the values.